# Why is my C++ program not working?

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a program that reads numbers from "bac.txt" and returns the 2 digit number/numbers (10,11,12,...,99) that appear most frequently. For example if the file "bac.txt" contains 393 17775787 72194942 12121774 it will return 77 and 21. I have managed to build a working function `counter(int n)` that can count how many times `n` is found in the file and returns `i` which is the number of times `n` has been found. Now I can't seem to find a way to print to the screen the number/numbers that are found most often. I tried to use some kind of for loop but it doesn't work. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int counter(int n){
  int i=0,j=0;
  char x1=n/10+'0';
  char x2=n%10+'0';
  char a;
  char b=NULL;

fstream fisier("bac.txt", fstream::in);
while (fisier >> noskipws >> a) {
        if(b==x1&&a==x2)
        i++;
        b=a;
}
return i;
}
int main()
{
int v[90];
int v1[90];
int i,maxim=0,nr;
for(i=10;i<100;i++)
{
    v[i]=counter(i);
    if(v[i]>maxim)maxim=v[i];
}

for(i=10;i<100;i++)
   if(v[i]==maxim)
   cout<<i;
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not helpful. Can you better explain what your program is intended to do, what this code actually does, and how that's incorrect? It's not clear what the problem might be here, but using C-style fixed-length arrays is never a good sign. The Standard Library has a number of useful containers like `std::vector` which are a better choice most of the time.

Comment: In `if (b==x1...)`, did you mean to leave out braces for the if-condition? Not that if you don't do that, only the immediate next line is executed as part of the if-loop, while the `b=a` line is executed always.

Comment: By saying "it doesn't work" you mean......?

Comment: Akshat Mahajan, yes I meant it.

Comment: This is a terrible way to do this. It's looping over all #s between 10 and 99, and each time the code rereads the file, looking for this sequence of characters. Even if you finish this, in order to come up with an answer you will end up rereading the same file 90 times. And, even if you finish this task, and hand this in as your project, I am confident that you will fail this assignment. I have no doubts that your teacher expects you to read the input file just once. Please try again, from scratch. As it is, the only thing this is good for, is a feature article on thedailywtf.com

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this program - starting with the formatting.  YIKES!

Comment: To be more precise, I need help finding a way to print to the screen the numbers that are found most frequently. The function counter(int n) returns the number of times n has been found in the specified file. As you can see I have tried using a for loop in which 'i=10;i<100;i++' and with each loop it assigns the value of 'counter(i)' to 'v[i]', at the same time, the 'maxim' variable is saving the biggest number that has been returned by 'counter(i)'. Then I used another for loop to print to the screen the value of 'i' for which 'v[i]==maxim'.

Comment: OK, so we have a complete program, the input, and the expected output (that is good).  We also need the *actual* output.  Then fix your formatting, and step through it in a debugger.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik, sorry for the bad code but I'm really new to this stuff. Also this is not an assgnment i'm just trying to learn C++ and from what I know so far this is the only method I could come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected the code.It works now.
You may check the changes.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int counter(int n)
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        char x1 = n / 10 + '0';
        char x2 = n % 10 + '0';
        char a;
        char b;

        fstream fisier("bac.txt", fstream::in);
        fisier >> b;
        while (fisier >> a) {
            if (b == x1 && a == x2)
                i++;
            b = a;
        }
        return i;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int v[101];
        int i, maxim = 0, nr;
        for (i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
            v[i] = counter(i);
            if (v[i] > maxim)
                maxim = v[i];
        }

        for (i = 10; i < 100; i++)
            if (v[i] == maxim)
                cout << i;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that you changed the file reading part in the counter function. Was it the reason why the program wasn't working?

Comment: Yes. Also I changed the  size of 'v' so as to store numbers above 90.

Answer (score -1):

i can't say you why your program's not working, but i can say you how i'd solve it. you have to store in an int vector the 2 digit number that you read from file (ex. if file contains 1234 the int vector will contains 12 23 34) than you have to find the 2 number that appear most times, so, you have read the first vector element and store it in a variable, than you count how many times it appear in the vector and you save the number you were searching in max_a and the times it appear in max_times_a (remember that when you find in the vector the number you're searching you have to put a -1 on it) than you search in the vector another number and count how many times it appear (putting -1 on that number) than you store that number in max_b and the times it appears in max_times_b. than what you have to do is to slide the vector and if you reach the end becouse you only read -1 you have max_a and max_b as result, but if you find a number you have to count how many times it appear and checking if it appear most times of max_a or max_b, and in case it appear most times you have to swap the values. i hope to have been useful to you.

- Tommaso